# Parsing asn1 document with openssl C API

Tags: c, parsing, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I'd like to parse certificate in asn1 format using openssl library. 
Unfortunately, some API commands lack relevant documentation so I've tried them on my own. I've seen many relations to this topic but no precise usage explanation.

for start I'll consider the following command that should return general asn1 object.

```
int ASN1_get_object(const unsigned char **pp, long *plength, int *ptag,
                int *pclass, long omax);
```

From examples i've found over the web, it seems like the input parameters description is as follow:

pp - pointer to the beginning of the object (or the certificate), it's changeable since after applying the function, this value move to the next object.

plength - output that represent the length of the object.

ptag - output that represent object type (simple like INTEGER, or complex the SEQUENCE).

pclass - I've no idea what does it means.

omax - the length until certificate end.

perhaps some openssl experienced user may validate my summary above, and clerify what does pclass means.

thanks

Comment: In this case, there appears to be no documentation, even for [OpenSSL 1.1.0](http://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/) (check in the `crypto` section). You will have to go to the code: `cd <openssl src dir>; grep -IR ASN1_get_object *`. Then, when you find a hit in a source file, you study it.

Comment: @jww, thanks for the help, i actually did that, wrote what i've understood, and requested help in what I haven't. perhaps you know the meaning of pclass ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Answer

The `pclass` parameter represents the Tag Class which the Tag Number of the object's type is in.

---

### Explanation

First, some background on an ASN.1 object. I'm going to simplify a lot here for the sake of explanation. When an ASN.1 object is encoded using BER/DER encoding, it's *generally* in the following structure:

```
+-------------------+---------------+-----------------+
| Identifier octets | Length octets | Contents octets |
| (Type)            | (Length)      | (Value)         |
+-------------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

The Identifier Octets are 8 bits which specify the type of the value. The Identifier Octets are usually encoded like this:

```
     +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
Bits |  8  |  7  |  6  |  5  |  4  |  3  |  2  |  1  |
     +-----------+-----+-----------------------------+
     | Tag class | P/C |         Tag number          |
     +-----------+-----+-----------------------------+
```

The Tag Class could be one of 4 things - Universal, Application,
Context-specific, or Private. The Universal class contains the types
which are native to ASN.1 (like Integer and String). Unless you're
dealing with custom types, you can expect the class to be Universal,
specified by `00`. This is what gets returned via the `pclass`
parameter.

The Tag Number is the 5 bits which specify the type within that class. This gets returned via the `ptag` parameter. For example, an Integer within the Universal class has the tag number `00010`.

So, for example, you could test you got an ASN.1 Integer from `ASN1_get_object` in the following way:

```c
ASN1_get_object(&pp, &plength, &ptag, &pclass, omax);
if (pclass == V_ASN1_UNIVERSAL && ptag == V_ASN1_INTEGER)
{
    // this is the native ASN.1 Integer type
}
```

If you know you're dealing purely with universal types, you might decide that testing the `pclass` variable is a bit redundant.

---

### Documentation

Some of your definitions of what the parameters do are a little off. Here's my attempt at documentation for the function. I should point out I've tried to figure this out on my own by looking at the code and the ASN.1 spec, so I'd welcome any edits if I've got anything wrong.

> ```c
> int ASN1_get_object(const unsigned char **pp, long *plength, int *ptag, int *pclass, long omax)
> ```
>
> **Summary**: Decodes a BER/DER-encoded ASN.1 object into its type, length and starting position of its value.
>
> **Parameters**:
>
> `**pp`: A pointer to a pointer to the start of the BER/DER encoded object. When the function returns, this pointer is adjusted to point to the start of the ASN.1 value (the contents octets).
>
> `*plength`: A pointer to a `long`. When the function returns, this contains the length of the ASN.1 value, specified as a number of octets. If the length was encoded in the indefinite form, `plength` will be 0.
>
> `*ptag`: A pointer to an `int`. When the function returns, this contains the ASN.1 Tag Number, which defines the type of the value. Note this is only the Tag Number, and doesn't include the Tag Class or the Primitive/Constructed indicator.
>
> `*pclass`: A pointer to an `int`. When the function returns, this contains the class of the ASN.1 Tag.
>
> `omax`: The maximum length of the BER/DER encoded object. If the object is longer than this, an error occurs.
>
> **Returns**: An integer. If the 8th bit is set (`0x80`) then an error occurred. If the 6th bit is set (`0x20`) then the type is a constructed type (i.e. the contents octets encode one or more data values). If the 1st bit is set (`0x01`) then the length of the value is indefinite, and the value will end with the 'end-of-contents octets'.